# Undefined symbols compiling GTK+ 3 with ATK 2.2.0 on CentOS 6

Tags: gtk, makefile, centos, undefined-symbol, centos6

I'm trying to compile GTK+ 3 with ATK 2.2.0 on CentOS, but am getting an error with atk_window_get_type:

```
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/mms/Source/gtk+/gtk'
  GISCAN Gtk-3.0.gir
/home/mms/Source/gtk+/gtk/tmp-introspectRXT5FI/.libs/lt-Gtk-3.0: symbol lookup error: /home/mms/Source/gtk+/gtk/.libs/libgtk-3.so.0: undefined symbol: atk_window_get_type
Command '['/home/mms/Source/gtk+/gtk/tmp-introspectRXT5FI/Gtk-3.0', '--introspect-dump=/home/mms/Source/gtk+/gtk/tmp-introspectRXT5FI/functions.txt,/home/mms/Source/gtk+/gtk/tmp-introspectRXT5FI/dump.xml']' returned non-zero exit status 127
```

As far as I can see it's declared in atk/atkwindow.h but is never defined, but there doesn't seem to be anyone else with this issue so I'm wondering why it's affecting me?

Answer (score -2):

from debian unstable

```
libglib2.0-0                             2.30.2-4 
libgtk-3-0                               3.2.2-3                          GTK+ graphical user interface library

gir1.2-atk-1.0                           2.2.0-2                          ATK accessibility toolkit (GObject introspection)

libatk1.0-0                              2.2.0-2                          ATK accessibility toolkit

libatk1.0-data                           2.2.0-2                          Common files for the ATK accessibility toolkit

libatkmm-1.6-1                           2.22.6-1                         C++ wrappers for ATK accessibility toolkit (shared libraries

eog: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0: undefined symbol: atk_window_get_type
```